# Possible criterion for proving parallelogram.

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, quadrilateral

A quadrilateral $ABCD$ has $∠BAD = ∠BCD$ and diagonal $AC$ bisects diagonal $BD$ at $P$. Is it necessarily a parallelogram? If not, give an example of such a quadrilateral. Provide proof.
[image]

---

I was thinking about this, please tell if I am wrong.

Assume $∠BAC > ∠ACD$, for now.

Taking $∠BAC = ∠ACD + k$ and $∠BCA = ∠CAD + k$

Marking $∠BAX = k $ and $∠BCY = k$, where $X$ and $Y$ are points on $BD$.

proved $AX || BC$ and $CY || AD$

$∠CAD = ∠ACY$
which proves

$∆PAD$ ~ $∆PCY$

ie. $AP/PC = DP/PY$

*(From this point on see user’s answer. The following part is WRONG)*

And similarly,
$∆CPD$ ~ $∆APX$

ie. $AP/PC = DP/PX$

and using these similarity ratios showed that $X = Y$.

Hence $AXCD$ is a parallelogram; where at $P$, $AP = PC,\,PX = DP = PB$ which proved $X = B$. So $ABCD $ must be a parallelogram.

Similarly, we can prove for $∠BAC < ∠ACD$, and for $∠BAC = ∠ACD$ it is obvious.

**Please use highschool geometry.**

Comment: I think one can prove that in a simpler way with a different RAA reasoning.

Comment: What is Raa reasoning?

Comment: Reductio Ad Absurdum: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be plausible. So should I take this statement as true?

Comment: I would suppose $PA\ne PC$ and show this leads to absurd consequences.

Comment: It is not much better now, since the drawing and the description in the text do not match. Besides you should write in details which "simple similarity ratios" you used to establish $X=Y$ ( I do not see any).

Comment: Hopefully, I have put enough clarification.

Comment: @AdityaGautam no you have not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big hint: As the angles at $A$ and $C$ are equal both points must lie on arc of the same radius over $BD$.

[image: Parallelogram]

Obviously -- due to symmetry -- triangles $ADB$ and $CBD$ are congruent.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong in the first line itself. If you want to take this approach then you have to use directed angles modulo $\pi$ or take separate boring cases, how do you know that $\angle BAC \geq \angle ACD$? Also, how are the two $k$'s the same in both the expressions?

Comment: Ok I just put that as a condition, now how to proceed?

Comment: The two $k’s$ are the same because ∠=∠.

Comment: Well, again you did wrong. You assumed $\angle BAC>\angle ACD$ , you assume strict inequality, it should be $\geq$

Comment: And what are you assuming? I would suggest going through basics once more

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you proof is false, as you have succeeded to prove $X=Y$ without using the equality $BP=PD$ and without this condition the claim is not valid as the next drawing (where $\angle BAD=\angle BCD$) shows:
[image]

There arises of course the question: what is wrong with your "simple similarity ratios"? Elaborating the issue one eventually finds the source (which was hidden behind the word "similarly"):
$$
\triangle PAD\sim \triangle PCY\implies \frac{PY}{PC}=\frac{PD}{PA}\implies\frac{PY}{PD}=\frac{PC}{PA},\\
\triangle PCD\sim \triangle PAX\implies \frac{PX}{PA}=\frac{PD}{PC}\implies\frac{PX}{PD}=\color{red}{\frac{PA}{PC}}.\\
$$

This invalidates the whole "proof" (assuming $PA\ne PC$).

Comment: Thanks sir/mam, for pointing out my stupid mistake, but do you imply that the statement was false? If so could you give an example of a quadrilateral which follows this Condition but is still not a parallelogram.

Comment: @AdityaGautam The original statement ($ABCD$ is a parallelogram) is correct. You just failed to prove it.

Comment: @AdityaGautam ... and I do not see a way to improve your proof, based on the assumption $AB\not\parallel CD$. The correct idea is to demonstrate  $(BP=PD,\;AP\ne PC)\implies\angle BAD\ne \angle BCD$.

Answer (score 0):

(I did not look at your proof.)

Draw the circumcircle $\gamma$  of the triangle $ABD$. Let $\gamma'$ be the circle obtained by reflecting $\gamma$ on the line $B\vee D$. The two circles then form a fourfold symmetric part of the figure, because there is also a symmetry with respect to the normal of $B\vee D$ erected at $P$.

We have $C\in \gamma'$  because of the peripheral angles, and   $C\in A\vee P$. It follows that $|CP|=|AP|$, because of the fourfold symmetry. If $\sigma$ is the point-reflection of the plane at $P$ then
$$\sigma:\quad\triangle(ADC)\to\triangle(CBA)\ .$$
This implies that the sides of $ABCD$ are pairwise parallel.

[image]

Comment: The question was "Please either tell me that its right or please point out my mistake."

Comment: @user: I don't think it is necessary that three fullfledged mathematicians independently certify that an assumed proof has mistakes. If we would go along this road we would only see bullshit proofs in the questions and trials of making the most of them in the answers.